# ID Column gets not created when using @Inheritance. "Column 'id' is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this class

```
@Entity(name = "foo")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
abstract class Base(
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    val someType: SomeType
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    val id: Long = 0

    @Column
    val created: Date = Date()

    @Column
    val updated: Date = Date()
}
```

Which I use here

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bar")
class Bar(
    @Column var a: Double? = null,
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "some_id")
    val cat: Cat
) : Base(
    someType = SomeType.variable_amount
)
```

WhenI try to do an `INSERT` I get the following error

> [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement [ERROR: cannot insert into column "id" Detail: Column "id" is an identity column defined as GENERATED ALWAYS. Hint: Use OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE to override.]

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the table `bar` with pgAdmin and the column `id` was of type `bigint`. Apparently, it automatically add an `IDENTIDY CONSTRAINT` (not sure why, maybe the column `id` was of `bigserial` before).

```
ALTER TABLE public.bar ALTER COLUMN id DROP IDENTITY;
```

drops the `CONSTRAINT` and the `INSERT` triggered by the `@Inheritance` works!